# .htaccess url rewrite with get parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I have an issue with my htaccess that will make me completely crazy.

I would like to replace event.php?id=158 by event/158
and event.php?id=158&display=documents by event/158/documents

I have found lot's of example doing this but it doesn't works in case and I do not understand why.

If I my rule is

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^event([0-9]+)$  event.php?id=$1  [L]
```

Then the id paramter is in dump($_REQUEST)

```
Array ( [id] => 158 [SERVERID94994] => 134038 [PHPSESSID] => 70ed00f7c3854afa31a0d8d5d4a02840 )
```

But with

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^event/([0-9]+)$  event.php?id=$1  [L]
```

Then id parameter is no more available in $_REQUEST

```
Array ( [SERVERID94994] => 134038 [PHPSESSID] => 70ed00f7c3854afa31a0d8d5d4a02840 ) 
=> Missing id
```

Please can you explain me what's wrong with the second rule?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to disable MultiViews:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

The [Apache docs on mod_negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html), describes what the Multiviews Option does, when enabled:

> If the
>   server receives a request for /some/dir/foo and /some/dir/foo does not
>   exist, then the server reads the directory looking for all files named
>   foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those
>   files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it
>   would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then
>   chooses the best match to the client's requirements, and returns that
>   document.

Use:

```
options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^event/([0-9]+)$  event.php?id=$1  [L]
```